# Python UDP class to control drone

Tags: python, multithreading, udp

I'm currently building a small plane with Raspberry Pi Zero W. I wrote a small code which uses [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) to control it.

Here I'm resending packets regularly in a thread because of the joystick input (it gives a lot of values when used and `time.sleep()` in a pygame event loop does bad things). Am I doing it the right way?

I'm also sending three bytes only per packets (which is enough for the control), but should I use power of 2 packet size? And why?

```
import socket
import struct
import time
import threading

S_TYPE = "BBB"


class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip="", port=8080, timeout=-1):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.bind((ip, port))
        if (timeout > 0):
            self.sock.settimeout(timeout)

    def recv(self):
        data = self.sock.recv(struct.calcsize(S_TYPE))
        res = struct.unpack("BBB", data)
        return (res)


class Client:
    def __init__(self, ip, port=8080, interval=100):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.data = (0, 0, 0)
        self.interval = interval
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.send_loop)
        self.thread.daemon = True
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.running = True

    def send(self, data_bytes):
        self.sock.sendto(data_bytes, (self.ip, self.port))

    def send_loop(self):
        '''Send loop is used to regulary send data in a thread'''
        while (self.running):
            self.lock.acquire()
            data_bytes = struct.pack(S_TYPE, *self.data)
            self.lock.release()
            self.send(data_bytes)
            time.sleep(self.interval / 1000.0)

    def update(self, a, b, c):
        '''Update data which is sent'''
        self.lock.acquire()
        self.data = (a, b, c)
        self.lock.release()

    def start(self):
        self.thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        # __del__ wouldn't be called with a thread running
        self.running = False
```

EDIT: do you see any problem not using a lock for self.running?

Answer (score 4):

Some notes:

- `data` as a name has been criticised [elsewhere](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/post/the_worlds_two_worst_variable.html); I would simply say that any variable or property should be self-explanatory within context. `a`, `b`, and `c` should also have more descriptive names.
- You don't need `self.ip` and `self.port` in the server - they are only used in the constructor. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).
- You should default `timeout` to `None` and forward it directly to the [socket configuration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout). Making your code have different `timeout` semantics from the `socket` library is probably just going to cause confusion.
- Why `return (res)` instead of `return res`?

Comment: IP and port of the server might be useful. On the other hand, you can probably obtain them from the bound socket. **EDIT** OK, you win.

Answer (score 4):

#### Client

In `__init__` you should have

```
    self.running = False
```

and `start` should look like this:

```
def start(self):
    if not self.running:
        self.running = True
        self.thread.start()
```

---

Instead of

```
self.lock.acquire()
self.data = (a, b, c)
self.lock.release()
```

it's safer and more elegant to write

```
with self.lock:
  self.data = (a, b, c)
```

---

Parentheses aren't necessary in

```
while (self.running):
```

Answer (score 3):

You extracted `"BBB"` into a pseudo-const, which is good.
However, you missed one:

```
res = struct.unpack("BBB", data)
```

This obviously should've been:

```
res = struct.unpack(S_TYPE, data)
```

If you aren't sure whether you replaced them all, `Ctrl + F` works in pretty much all editors. Often there's even a search and replace :-)

Comment: You could also make it even more obvious and add it to the constructor as it's only used inside the class.

Comment: @Dex'ter it is used in two classes